# Remove Unavailable Items from Form Runner

Tags: orbeon

I have run into a bit of trouble when using orbeon-2018.2.3.201905172253-PE.

I created some test forms to trial out of the functionality. I have removed them from the builder but cannot work out how to remove them from the form runner, I have already made them unavailable.

I have tried to documentation on Orbeon's website and used the following SQL, however the form still persists in the form runner.

```
SELECT *
FROM   orbeon_form_data
WHERE  document_id IN
       (
           SELECT t.document_id
           FROM   orbeon_form_data t,
                  (
                      SELECT   max(last_modified_time) last_modified_time,
                               app, form, document_id
                      FROM     orbeon_form_data
                      GROUP BY app, form, document_id
                  ) m
           WHERE  -- Look at "last row" in the "journal"
                  t.last_modified_time = m.last_modified_time AND
                  t.app                = m.app                AND
                  t.form               = m.form               AND
                  t.document_id        = m.document_id        AND
                  -- Take deleted items
                  deleted = 'Y'                               
       )
```

[image: Orbeon Form Runner]

Any assistance would be great as I feel like I am going around in circles.

Comment: Hi James, I think you're trying to remove published forms. If you'd like to do this at the SQL level, you'll want to remove them from the `orbeon_form_definition` table. If you want to do this with the UI, then you can mark them as unavailable on the Form Runner home page, which you seem to have done based on the screenshot you attached. Were you maybe looking for something different? ‑Alex

Comment: I was hoping to just completely remove the unpublished forms from the UI. It it only possible if I delete them from the database?

Comment: Hi James, correct, it is right now only possible to completely delete the published forms by removing them "manually" from the database, i.e. running your own SQL. But I understand some use cases can call for completely published forms. I've created RFE [4154](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4154); does that fit what you're looking for? ‑Alex

Comment: Hi James, did you get a chance to look at RFE [#4154](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4154)? If so, is it inline with what you are looking for? ‑Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this writing, you can either:

- Completely remove published form by running your own SQL, deleting rows from the `orbeon_form_definition` table and related tables.
- On the Form Runner home in admin mode, you can mark forms as unavailable.

Also see [RFE #4154](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4154).